# Passing multiple values to a single PowerShell script parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a script to which I pass server name(s) in $args.

This way I can do stuff to this (these) server(s) using `foreach`:

```
.\script.ps1 host1 host2 host3

foreach ($i in $args)
{
    Do-Stuff $i
}
```

I'd like to add a named optional parameter called vlan. I've tried:

```
Param(
    [string]$vlan
)

foreach ($i in $args)
{
    Write-Host $i
}
Write-Host $vlan
```

It works if you pass a `-vlan` parameter but if you don't then the script auto assigns the last server name to `$vlan`.

So, how can you pass single or multiple parameters plus an optional named parameter to a PowerShell script?

Ideally, here are valid examples:

```
.\script.ps1 host1
.\script.ps1 host1 host2 host3
.\script.ps1 host1 host2 -vlan office
```

Answer (score 231, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use two parameters: One for hosts (can be an array), and one for vlan.

```
param([String[]] $Hosts, [String] $VLAN)
```

Instead of

```
foreach ($i in $args)
```

you can use

```
foreach ($hostName in $Hosts)
```

If there is only one host, the foreach loop will iterate only once. To pass multiple hosts to the script, pass it as an array:

```
myScript.ps1 -Hosts host1,host2,host3 -VLAN 2
```

...or something similar.

Comment: thanks for including the info on how to call the script - I'm often missing little pieces like that in powershell.

Comment: If you are executing outside a powershell (in wsl for example), then you need to use the `-Command` flag and to quote the variable.  `pwsh -Command myScript.ps1 -Hosts "host1,host2,host3" -VLAN 2`

Comment: @miah Nice one. I'd adjust your command a little bit like `pwsh -Command .\myScript.ps1 -Hosts "host1,host2,host3" -VLAN 2`

Answer (score 35):

One way to do it would be like this:

```
 param(
       [Parameter(Position=0)][String]$Vlan,
       [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)][String[]]$Hosts
    ) ...
```

This would allow multiple hosts to be entered with spaces.

Comment: Really nice! Except your example is missing a ']' to close the second Parameter attribute.

Comment: This one should be the best answer.

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: I don't see how this allows `vlan` to be optional.

Comment: @Tony all parameters are optional by default.  You can add the line `[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]` before `[string]$vlan
` if you want for readability.  But it won't change functionality.

Answer (score 30):

Parameters take input before arguments. What you should do instead is add a parameter that accepts an array, and make it the first position parameter. ex:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    [string[]]$Hosts,
    [string]$VLAN
    )

foreach ($i in $Hosts)  
{ 
    Do-Stuff $i
}
```

Then call it like:

```
.\script.ps1 host1, host2, host3 -VLAN 2
```

Notice the comma between the values. This collects them in an array

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues doing this in my yml file and then I found this link and adding "-Command" to the front of my script solved it:

https://michlstechblog.info/blog/powershell-passing-an-array-to-a-script-at-command-line/

Answer (score -7):

I call a scheduled script who must connect to a list of Server this way:

```
Powershell.exe -File "YourScriptPath" "Par1,Par2,Par3"
```

Then inside the script:

```
param($list_of_servers)
...
Connect-Viserver $list_of_servers.split(",")
```

The split operator returns an array of string

Comment: This is a horrible way to do it.  You should be making $list_of_servers an array: `[string[]]$list_of_servers`

Comment: Thank you, never realized it was so scary. That works from many years.