# Powershell: Pass multiple values (with spaces) to an argument

Tags: powershell

I have a script that uses multiple arguments, some of which contain spaces. The script is called from another script, so I pass the arguments to it from variables with the calling script.

Calling script:

```
$script = "C:\Path\script.ps1"
$arg1 = "SomeValue"
$arg2 = "1234"
$arg3 = @("Value1","Some Value","Value 2")
$arg4 = $true
Invoke-Command $script -Arg1 $arg1 -Arg2 $arg2 -Arg3 $arg3 -Arg4 $arg4
```

The called script looks like this:

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=0)]
[String]$arg1,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)]
[String]$arg2,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
[array]$arg3,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=3)]
[bool]$arg4
)

# Do stuff with the arguments
```

When I call the script, I get the following error:

```
"A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Some'."
```

I've also manually called the script (bypassing the calling script) in a powershell window as below:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass C:\Path\script.ps1 -Arg1 "SomeValue" -Arg2 "1234" -Arg3 @("Value1","Some Value","Value 2") -Arg4 $true

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass C:\Path\script.ps1 -Arg1 "SomeValue" -Arg2 "1234" -Arg3 "Value1","Some Value","Value 2" -Arg4 $true

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass C:\Path\script.ps1 -Arg1 "SomeValue" -Arg2 "1234" -Arg3 "Value1","SomeValue","Value2" -Arg4 $true

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass C:\Path\script.ps1 -Arg1 "SomeValue" -Arg2 "1234" -Arg3 "Value1,SomeValue,Value2" -Arg4 $true
```

None of these variations work. I've also tried the ideas found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152740/how-to-pass-an-array-as-a-parameter-to-another-script) by changing the Arg3 value to (,$args) but that doesn't work. I also changed the parameter type as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120597/passing-multiple-values-to-a-single-powershell-script-parameter), but that didn't work either.

The goal is to be able to pass multiple variables (some with spaces) to the script through an argument/parameter.

**EDIT 12/22/16**: The goal includes passing this same information from a shortcut/typed command. For example, my calling script creates a RunOnce entry in the registry to reference the called script and places the arguments in the call just like the manual examples above. None of them work, either.

```
Set-ItemProperty $RegROPath "(Default)" -Value "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass $scriptPath $argumentList" -type String
```

Comment: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass --% "C:\Path\script.ps1 -Arg1 \"SomeValue\" -Arg2 \"1234\" -Arg3 \"Value1\",\"Some Value\",\"Value 2\" -Arg4 $true"`

Comment: Hello PetSerAl, I will be building this programatically, so the values will need to come from the splatted array.

Comment: It can be done. You just need to apply proper escaping everywhere.

Comment: So I need to include quotes in the array elements by escaping? I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Invoke-Command` With `&` or `.`

Use `&` if all you want is output, `.` if you want it to run in the current context (e.g. retain all variables set)

`Get-Help about_Scripts` for more detail (or read [online version here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts))

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, it's not your script that is throwing that error, it's `Invoke-Command`.  If you absolutely have to use `Invoke-Command` you need (running remotely for example) to pass the arguments as the parameter `ArgumentList` like this:

```
$script = "C:\Path\script.ps1"
$argumentList = @(
    '-arg1 "SomeValue"',
    '-arg2 1234',
    '-arg3 @("Value1","Some Value","Value 2")',
    '-arg4 $true'
)
Invoke-Command -FilePath $script -ArgumentList $argumentList
```

**Edit 2:**

> I will try your suggestion as soon as I am able to. One question, what if I need to add a conditional argument? Currently, I add arguments to the list with $argumentlist += ("arg5", "value"). Some of them are conditional: if ($bool) {$argumentlist += ("arg5", "value")}. Is there a way to do that in your example?

Yes you can, the `$argumentList` variable in the example is an array like any other.  It can be defined all at once, defined empty and added to later, or any mix.

*Example*

```
$argumentList = @(
    '-arg1 "SomeValue"',
    '-arg2 1234',
    '-arg3 @("Value1","Some Value","Value 2")',
    '-arg4 $true'
)
if ($bool) {
    $argumentList += '-arg5 "value"'
}
Invoke-Command -FilePath $script -ArgumentList $argumentList
```

But again, unless you are running the command on a remote computer or PSSession, you should use `&` or dot sourcing (`.`).  You can still add arguments conditionally using splatting ([about_Splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting))

*Example*

```
$scriptParamsSplat = @{
    arg1 = "SomeValue"
    arg2 = 1234
    arg3 = @("Value1","Some Value","Value 2")
    arg4 = $true
}
if ($bool) {
    $scriptParamsSplat.arg5 = "value"
}
& 'C:\Path\To\script.ps1' @scriptParamsSplat
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion as soon as I am able to. One question, what if I need to add a conditional argument? Currently, I add arguments to the list with $argumentlist += ("arg5", "value"). Some of them are conditional: if ($bool) {$argumentlist += ("arg5", "value")}. Is there a way to do that in your example?

Comment: The script call with splatted arguments fails with "Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Arg3'. Cannot convert value to type System.String". Also, the calling script creates a RunOnce call to the script to persist through a reboot. When the script is called again, I get the same errors (see the manual examples in my original post). How can I have an array of values (with spaces) as an argument from a RunOnce/shortcut/Scheduled Task?

Comment: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -Command "& 'pathtoscript' -Arg1 @(1, 2, 3)"`

Comment: As for the splat failing, make sure you aren't surrounding the array definition with quotes.

Comment: My argument declaration looks exactly like yours. The only quotes are around the strings.

Comment: Oh the error is that it's trying to convert it **to** a string not from. Did you change the parameter definition from [array] to [string]?

Comment: I had changed it to troubleshoot something else and thought I changed it back, but it was a different param that got changed.  1st call working now. For the RunOnce call, to make sure I understand your response above, there is only one argument? How does that translate from the splatted argument list above? Do the numbers represent values in the array?