# How do I populate an unknown number of variables from user input dynamically in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to populate an unknown number of variables based on user input (writing a script that obtains certificates from a CA, and sometimes these certificates contain more than one name (SANs) and it is impossible to know how many so this needs to be dynamic).

I know I start with setting up params like this:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string[]]$SANs
)
```

And then I need to somehow take those values and assign them to `$san1, $san2, $san3` and so on.

Being new to programming, I am not even sure what to call this.  Would you use a `foreach` loop to somehow populate these variables?

```
ForEach ($SAN in $SANs) {
```

what do I do here?

```
}
```

The end result is a need to populate a string with these variables like `dns=$san1&dns=$san2&dns=$san3` etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing multiple values to a single PowerShell script parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120597/passing-multiple-values-to-a-single-powershell-script-parameter)

Comment: The `$SAN` in your `foreach` would act as each individual item. Ex: Inside your `foreach` put `Write-Host $SAN` this will hopefully give you a better understanding on what is going on.

Comment: So, you're trying to do `'dns=' + ($SANs -join 'dns=')` right?

Comment: Honestly I just put the `$SAN` variable right inline with the text (I'm making an output text/inf file that will be used to generate the request).  Like this: `_continue_ = "dns=$SAN"`r`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician only the `&` is missing from the `'dns=' + ($SANs -join '&dns=')`  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions and scripts can take parameters. The parameter block in your example looked like...

```
function foo {
    Param([string[]]$SANs)
}
```

That parameter, $SANs, is an array of strings. A single string would look like this...

```
$stuff = 'barf'
```

An array of strings looks like this...

```
$stuff = @('barf', 'toot', 'ruff', 'meow')
```

So far so good? If you need to get each of the things in the array, you'd use a loop...

```
foreach ($thing in $stuff) { write-output $thing }
```

...for example...

```
$san_declaration

foreach ($thing in $stuff) {
  if ($san_declaration.length -eq 0) {
    $san_declaration = "dns=${thing}"
  } else {
    $san_declaration += "&dns=${thing}"
  }
}
```

Now, if you (not that you asked) happen to be calling `Get-Certificate`, just remember the SANs parameter is a string array. In that case, you'd just pass in the string array instead of creating the string like you were doing.

```
Get-Certificate -DnsName $stuff
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Marked as answer.  Thank you for the thorough explanation.

Comment: My pleasure botha.