# Powershell Function output to logfile

Tags: powershell

Output Function update the data in txt file

```
Function LogWrite
{
    Param ([string]$logstring)
    $Logfile = "C:\temp\$(gc env:computername).txt"
    $logstring | out-file $LogFile -Append
}

Function readonly {
    $user=whoami
    $out=(Get-Acl "C:\temp").Access | Select-Object IdentityReference,FileSystemRights
    $acl = Get-Acl "C:\temp"
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user,"FullControl","Allow")
    $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
    LogWrite $user,$out
}readonly
```

Function `readonly` updates data to function `logwrite`.  It updates the results of `whoami` and `system.object`.

I need your help to update the results of `$out`.

Comment: Added powershell tag, formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

`LogWrite` expects one string parameter, but you're calling it with two parameters. You can either use string formatting to merge `$whoami` and `$out` via `LogWrite "User=$user, Out= $out"`. Or you change `LogWrite` that it takes an array of strings `[String[]]` (explained in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120597/passing-multiple-values-to-a-single-powershell-script-parameter) link).

Hope that helps.