# How can I run additional commands after an alias in Powershell?

Tags: android, powershell, adb, alias

In my job, I work a lot with different android devices and interface with them using adb. Rather than remembering or needing to copy their serial numbers or IP addresses to refer to them, I've been trying to use aliases, but I'm running into issues. I'm currently using a combination of functions and profiles to refer to the devices. This is my current Profile.ps1 file:

```
function googletv_func ($params){
    if ($params -eq "connect"){
        adb connect 192.168.0.14
    }
    else{
        adb -s 192.168.0.14 $params
    }
}

function firehd_func ($params){
    adb -s G0W1EW0 $params
}

Set-Alias googletv "googletv_func"
Set-Alias firehd "firehd_func"
```

If I enter the command "googletv connect", it will successfully connect to the google tv. But if I try something with more than one parameter following the alias (e.g. "googletv install example.apk" or "firehd shell pm list packages") it only executes the single parameter following the alias. Wondering what I'm missing and I appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43940404/1471828) answer.

Comment: This is not an issue of alias but an issue of how you're passing the parameters to your function.

Comment: Also, if you want to add an alias to your function you simply add `[alias('googletv_func')]` before the `param( )` block inside your function.